# Python cant connect to local MySQL server through socket

Tags: mysql, debian, python, socket

I have a python script which is designed to add things to a MYSQL database. The error I get is this:

```
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

I've checked the credentials of the database in the settings and they are correct and I can connect to the database via Sequel.

I installed the following packages:

```
apt-get -y install build-essential python-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev python-pip libmysqlclient-dev
pip install -U MySQL-python
```

I'm not really sure how to diagnose this. Is it looking for the mysqld.sock in the right place and it isn't there, or should it instead be looking for it in a different location.

Any help or advice would be much appreciated so I can move forward.

Comment: any reason not to install the `python-mysqldb` package instead of building it yourself?

Comment: I'm not sure, it was from a tutorial. Are you saying I can install that as a replacement to "MySQL-python"? I don't want to run a mysql server on my server, I just want to be able to connect to it and add a schema to it

Comment: The title of the question says "local MySQL server", yet you say you don't want to run a MySQL server on your server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A. If mysql is running on same server, find socket file and specify it to the application:

```
lsof|grep mysql.sock
```

or connect to the server using IP, not hostname (hostname "localhost" reverts to default socket connection, instead of TCP, defaults to /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock)

B. If mysql is running on the other server - connection parameters are not passed correctly to your script, check how it must run.

Also, some scripts may read `[client]` section from `~/.my.cnf`

Comment: I have the MYSQL server externally so when I run lsof|grep mysql.sock it returns nothing. I will look into option B now to make sure.

Comment: There is a way to change default string via ~/.my.cnf, but it's not recommended since all applications run with that user will be able to connect to this database by default, and if password is specified - they will be able to do even more than just "connect". Security.

Comment: @JamesWillson What do you mean that you "have the MYSQL server externally"?

Comment: good question for clarification. "so when I run lsof|grep mysql.sock it returns nothing", for me keyword is "so", probably he's not running it on localhost.